# Private Data Member Access

Tags: c++, private

I see the following piece of code from a c++ textbook, but I think it has an access problem.

Class A has a private data member `val` and a public member function `const A & topval(const A & b) const` which returns a object reference which has the larger val. I think the usage of `b.val` below is wrong since it accesses a private data from outside, is my understanding correct?

```
const A & A::topval(const A & b) const
{
   if (**b.val** > val) 
     return b;
   else 
     return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can access a private variable of an object from a member function of the object's class.